# Google Drive Sheet backed Bigquery Table can't handle the string "804932999580448"

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I have a really really odd issue that I can't figure out.

I have a Bigquery table that is backed by a Google Drive Sheet.  I've narrowed the issue down to a specific value in a specific cell.

My Sheet/Table has 4 nullable string columns, but the string in the first column only contains numbers (however I *do* want it to be a string type).  Here is the first and only row in my sheet (commas denote a new cell):

```
804932999580448,there,again,hi
```

SELECT * ing this table results in the following error:

> Reason: tableUnavailable. Message: Something went wrong with the table you queried. Contact the table owner for assistance.

Sample failed job id: bquijob_6e7305cd_15af78d1556

**This is where things get weird:** When you change the first number of the first value (i.e. to `704932999580448` or `904932999580448`) the query completes just fine.

Why does the specific value `804932999580448` cause this query to fail?

Comment: What project did you run these queries - this can help finding your failed jobs diagnostics.

Comment: Bizarre. I can reproduce. @MoshaPasumansky - any luck in finding out what the problem is? Here's an example with project id: `river-formula-161601:bquijob_705407b6_15afadb4015`

Comment: While I don't have more concrete updates at this time - this is most certainly a bug, we are looking deeper into it.

Comment: Removed my project id comment, the project # for it is 452690959193 for the record